# Updating the axis of a highcharts chart object using jquery after inital render (django)

Tags: jquery, django, highcharts

I can seem to figure out a basic question

I’ve got a highcharts chart in my django app that is getting loaded in the template. The data for the chart is getting populated via ajax.

I’d like to add a button above the chart which if clicked toggles the axis to logarithmic (instead of the default, linear) but I can’t seem to make this work

Here’s my code

HTML

```
<button id="target" type='button' > switch to log </button>   
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     var chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'line',
        },
        title: {text: null},
        xAxis: {title: {text: null}, labels: {rotation: -45}},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Item counts'}, 
                type: 'linear',
                stackLabels: {enabled: true},
        },
        plotOptions: {column: {dataLabels: {enabled: false}, stacking: 'normal'}},
        series: [{}],        
    };

    var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'global_trend_chart' %}" ;  

    $.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
        function(data) {
            chartOptions.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['date'];
            chartOptions.series[0].name = 'Global counts';
            chartOptions.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['item_counts'];
            var chartA = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
    });

    $( "#target" ).click(function() {    
        chartA.update({
            yAxis: {
                type: 'logarithmic',
            }

        });

    });

} );

</script>
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tha `chartA` variable does not exist in the click callback function scope. You need to declare it on a higher level, for example:

```
var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'global_trend_chart' %}";  
var chartA;

$.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
    function(data) {
        chartOptions.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['date'];
        chartOptions.series[0].name = 'Global counts';
        chartOptions.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['item_counts'];
        chartA = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
});

$( "#target" ).click(function() {    
    chartA.update({
        yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic',
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4935/

Comment: Thanks. This works nicely for me with your simulated ajax function but when I try it with my actual ajax function shown above, it fails. When I console.log ChartA within the button click, I see the following error --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Comment: Hi @jay queue, Please try to add the click event listener in the `getJSON` callback function, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4936/